# What are these green text/line displays shown during the livestream of Crew Dragon's approach to dock with the ISS?

Tags: spacex, iss, docking

[image: Screenshot from a laptop display during livestream]

During [the livestream of Crew Dragon's approach to docking, at 6:24](https://youtu.be/fPmPUrE5IYI?t=384) a laptop display is shown with lots of green text and a camera view of the International Space Station.  What's going on?

Answer (score 62):

The display shown is from the screen of one of the Space Station Computer laptops in the US Lab.  This was being downlinked to Mission Control in Houston to monitor the functioning of tools used by the ISS crew to track the Crew Dragon's approach.

The foreground program is the Dragon 2 Docking Monitor, which takes video supplied by the Crew Dragon (aka Dragon 2, Docking Dragon) and overlays a grid to estimate angular offsets in the view alongside some pertinent information for docking (range and lateral offset between the docking adapters, rates, a couple of modes).

The background program is RPOP, the Rendezvous and Proximity Operations Program.  The Space Shuttle version of RPOP is described in [JSC 63400 "History of Space Shuttle Rendezvous,"](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110023479.pdf) page 239 and others.  A new version of RPOP, version 8, was created to monitor the approach and rendezvous of Crew Dragon and CST-100 to the International Space Station.  The screenshot shows the Demo Mission 1 Crew Dragon at the very edge of the Keep Out Sphere (Range, R, 200 meters).

"Coincidentally" I happen to have been the lead developer on RPOP since 2015 and monitored its operation from Houston during Demo Mission 1.  I thought it was conceivable that someone might have wondered what this was since it got livestreamed and has since ended up in places like a [Scott Manley video](https://youtu.be/qdZNG-tQ724?t=413).

Comment: Thanks for Q & A! Good job,too. Glad to hear RPOP is still around.  I suppose DOUG is too, but not RSAD.

Comment: DOUG definitely is still around.  ROBO uses it to help with SA during EVAs, among other things.  RSAD I'm not familiar with, but very few things at JSC ever actually go away.

Comment: RSAD was SRMS specific I think.

Comment: I feel I'm incomplete because I have no idea what RSAD, DOUG, ROBO and SRMS are. Although it's pretty clear these are not vital to the answer and getting to know what they mean will result in hours on Wikipedia et al, I'd still love to know what they stand for.

Comment: DOUG is "Dynamic Ubiquitous Onboard Graphics," a 3D engine/model system I'm not too familiar with.  ROBO is a console position/group that handles robotics (arms, etc) on the space station.  [S]SRMS is the [Space] Station Robotic Manipulation System I think, so the main arm on the ISS.  But RSAD is beyond me.

Comment: _Why_ wouldn't they call it the Proximity and Rendezvous Operations Program...

Comment: RSAD was the Robotics Situational Awareness Display. It showed bar graphs of the shuttle arm joint angles and produced spoken annunciations in a female voice if you got too close to the joint limits - "Reach limit!" "Soft stop!" "Singularity alert!". Like the "pull up! pull up!" warnings in airplanes.  SRMS was the shuttle robot arm, SSRMS is the station robot arm.

Comment: @ErinAnne Small question: during the live stream, one of the presenters called this view the 'LIDAR image' or something similar. I know what LIDAR is, and could imagine there are 2D scanning systems, but this image seems just some sort of B&W or thermal image, with a single LIDAR distance ranging reported as a number. If it were a LIDAR image, I would expect the closest part to have a different color, but instead it seems to show some reflections. Can you clarify what type of camera this is? And what kind of other sensors are there, I know there must be several ...

Comment: @Bas that's a whole other question about what sensors are on Dragon 2.  The image of the ISS is from a grayscale centerline/hatch camera and is def not a LIDAR image.

Comment: @Bas you are encouraged to ask this kind of question on the main page, not in a comment! It's completely on topic.

Comment: @Celos because PROP already meant something and there are enough confusing acronyms already.