# How much technical information is given to astronauts on a spaceflight? How much of it is left to the control center?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, mission-control

In many space exploration movies, we see that the control center, most notably the [Mission Control Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_C._Kraft_Jr._Mission_Control_Center) has a team of engineers and scientists communicating with the astronauts regarding a variety of things like altitude, propulsion, etc.

But we also see that the astronauts themselves have a lot of technical understanding. They take exams, undergo severe training, etc.

So just how much more information/help does the MCC provide? In other words, for what reasons/data do the astronauts rely on the MCC for, that they cannot possibly realize or figure out themselves?

I was not sure as to how much more data the MCC has because it seems to me that almost all of the data that the MCC provides to the astronauts would already be accessible to them inside the spacecraft (like the fuel loads, the altitude, which engines are functioning, the speed, the thermal values, etc.).

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that, in the Shuttle days, while MCC certainly had lots more _insight_ into vehicle systems than did the crew at any given time, the ceiling on how much knowledge individual astronauts accrued during training was largely up to them. If an astronaut had a question about a particular aspect of spaceflight, they were given access to any number of subject experts.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

At least for shuttle, the MCC had a lot more detailed information than the crew does.

The crew was only provided with the information necessary for situational awareness and procedure execution. The MCC got a lot of detailed engineering data that the crew would not normally need. If they did end up needing it, they could get it from the MCC.

Here are some examples for a single system, the Remote Manipulator System (the robot arm).

The crew had a control panel that provided them with status indicator and caution lights, a rate meter, and three digital displays that could display one of 7 sets of data at a time.

[image: photograph of RMS control panel]
(Personal photograph from shuttle Endeavour)

They also had two computer displays. One provided status information, much of which was duplicated on the hardware panel. The second provided more detailed information on malfunctions.

[image: main RMS spec page]

[image: RMS error page]

(Source: [DPS Dictionary](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/359895main_DPS_G_K_7.pdf))

The Payload Deployment and Retrieval System flight controllers had access to much more information. Some of their displays are shown in this picture.

[image]
(Personal photo)

They also had generic capabilities like plotting graphs of any desired telemetry parameter.

---

A simple example of the difference between what the crew saw and the flight controller saw is as follows:

Let's say the crew encountered a malfunction of the arm's end effector while grappling a payload. The crew would get a caution light and tone, a fault message on the CRT screen, and possibly one or more "down arrows" under the CHECK CRT heading on the malfunction computer screen. The control panel also had six "talkbacks" giving information on the status microswitches in the end effector.

[image]

The flight controller would see the parameters that drove all these crew displays, and much more:

- Plots of the current being drawn by the motors in the end effector mechanism.
- Detailed telemetry information about the end effector drive commands generated by the Manipulator Control Interface Unit (MCIU) firmware in response to crew commands.
- Event time logs showing precisely when crew commands were entered in relation to when error messages or relevant telemetry data were emitted
- Telemetry showing whether relevant switch contacts are "made" or "broken" corresponding to the physical switch position
- Status of other internal flags generated by the MCIU according to its interpretation of the grapple's progress
- Built-In Test Equipment (BITE) status generated by the system

The flight controllers also had access to reference information not available to the crew: software listings, detailed schematics, engineering support from the Mission Evaluation Room, etc.

Comment: What's the red thingy on the velcro patch next to the Canadian flag on your first photo? A safety cover hiding a SRMS EMER JETT button?

Comment: @TooTea it is indeed a safety cover aka "switch guard", stowed there for possible use. I think the red color is more for "remove before flight" than an indication of criticality. Here is an example of some in use https://i.imgur.com/Gv8n57w.png The RMS jettison switches were not exactly hidden (they were behind a hinged cover), but they were on a different panel, one located below the one in the picture. https://i.imgur.com/4jn3ZVQ.png

Comment: Apologies for a trivial question, but what are those "talkbacks": magnet-actuated flags?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd not trivial at all! There's an explanation in answers here: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24138/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for that, interesting. So grey shutters moving in front of the "barber pole" diagonal stripes. When I saw the photos I was reminded of a 1960 'phone plugboard: I don't know whether this was intended for blind operators or if it was universal, but some (at least in the UK during the GPO monopoly) had pivoting aluminium "eyelids" which dropped over a dark recess.

Comment: @OrganicMarble those are some pretty amazing pictures you took.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I have held talkbacks pulled out of the simulator; from shaking them it seemed like the OP/barberpole/CL markings were printed on a single, slightly curved strip of metal that was weakly spring-loaded to the center "bp" position. Presumably the "open" and "closed" signals rotated the metal strip one way or the other. Never saw the innards, and don't know if the real vehicle tbs were the same at all - they probably weren't.

Comment: Very interesting. I would have guessed that the astronauts had *more* raw data available if they desired, both for logical and operational reasons (they are at the data source, and they may need it to fix problems when communication failed). Apparently, that intuition was dead wrong.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica this quote from Erin Anne's answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/63262/6944 is highly relevant "there's only so much attention the crew has to give compared to the amount of attention possessed by the small army on the ground." I worked on a project to upgrade the onboard displays (project cancelled after the Columbia failure) and a really enormous amount of detailed work goes into ensuring that the crew has all the information they need - but not extraneous information! - given the limited acreage of displays and control panels available.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica something else about that, which I thought about including in my answer but don't think I can legally support with any further detail, is that raw data can sometimes be misleading compared to processed data.  Imagine a system where the raw data looks like something you're familiar with (maybe even an expert with), but is actually qualitatively different.  I wish I could tell that story, it made me feel really smart at the time lol

Comment: @OrganicMarble Looking carefully at the photo, there's 3 layers: "barberpole" at the back, frame/separator, then a shutter. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19760026143/downloads/19760026143.pdf "electromagnetic device that drives a drum or shutter-type display. ... out-of-adjustment or out-of-socket jewel and pivot, and excessive flag excursion." So I think a lightweight grey flag/eyelid moving in front of a stationary "barberpole" with a jewelled pivot. Sorry, my level of nerdishness: people forget that LED indicators weren't realistic in the '70s, I've seen neons on early mainframes.

Comment: Hi @OrganicMarble, I missed asking this question earlier. But how were you able to take these photographs of your workspace? Are they not deemed confidential beyond a certain point or something?

Comment: @penguin99 Taking pictures of the shuttle cockpit, if you could get in, was totally OK and you could distribute them anywhere. As far as the MCC goes, at least at the end of the program, I could take in visitors, they could take all the pictures they wanted and distribute them anywhere; I could do the same. There are lots of official NASA photos showing MCC consoles https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/jsc2011e046832/jsc2011e046832~orig.jpg At least to this level, NASA MOD was pretty open. Back when DOD was involved in shuttle, it was totally different.

Answer (score 30):

I supported several visiting-vehicle-to-ISS rendezvous from the Mission Evaluation Room (MER) that Organic Marble mentions in his answer (supporting [RPOP](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34606/what-are-these-green-text-line-displays-shown-during-the-livestream-of-crew-drag/34607#34607)), and was involved in some of the procedures development and training for using RPOP for crewed vehicle rendezvous.  This could be considered a continuation of Marble's answer into post-Shuttle operations.

For these less-critical functions (we were supposed to be go for rendezvous if RPOP failed... and then we delayed rendezvous during Crew Dragon DM-1 because one of the RPOP laptops wouldn't talk to the data source) crew were taught how to use the tool, given procedures for how to fix it if it broke in the most likely ways, and then had subject-matter-expert backup on the ground for the things that were harder to predict.  I was also there to confirm the tool was operating properly, by running a separate copy on the ground using a copy of the data the on-orbit software was receiving.

A lot of the nature of the job I had (continuing development of a situational awareness tool) was trying to give the crew just enough technical information for them to make a call (do we trust that the vehicle is safely navigating to the station, or not?) and eliding the rest.  Technically the raw information was available elsewhere (and I think at least once I was told by someone in the Mission Operations Directorate that they'd rather use that instead), but there's only so much attention the crew has to give compared to the amount of attention possessed by the small army on the ground.